# Скажите, нужна ли в этом предложении запятая? "Думаешь, у тебя нет таланта?"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли в этом предложении запятая?

> Думаешь, у тебя нет таланта?

Comment: А Вы как думаете, нужна или нет?

Answer (score 2):

***Думаешь**, у тебя нет таланта?*

Запятая ставится. Слово ***думаешь*** можно считать **вводным словом** со значением обращения к собеседнику. Такой вариант больше соответствует интонации, а также позиции слова. Возможная замена:  *По-твоему, у тебя нет таланта?*

Другой вариант объяснения такой. Это **бессоюзное сложное предложение** (БСП) с изъяснительными отношениями. Вместо двоеточия используется запятая, так как нет интонационного **предупреждения,** то есть подчеркнутой паузы и понижения тона.

Comment: *со значением обращения к собеседнику* — значение предполагает какой-то смысл, а не цель.